# Is it possible to set whitespace rules when printing to SSMS "messages" panel?

Tags: ssms

This question relates to SSMS v. 17 (SQL Server Management Studio) .

T-SQL has a command to print remarks (`Print N'text...'`) to the message panel as scripts run.

For example:

```
-- Non-School Days
PRINT N'...inserting "Non-School Days" errors into dbo.ErrorLog';
/*
    ... T-SQL Code ...
*/
GO

PRINT N'...inserting "No campus-student match" errors into dbo.ErrorLog';
/*
    ... T-SQL Code ...
*/
GO

/*   ... and so on... */
```

The default behavior of message rendering is to place whitespace between the printed message and the `(x row affected)` message generated by SSMS.

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to describe. My question is whether there is a way to change the whitespace rules so that statements related to the same query are visually grouped together. I drew red lines to identify the correct grouping.

I looked in SSMS for "whitespace" or "message" options (I found none). If there are existing answers to the this question, perhaps I'm not asking the right question or using the correct keywords. Is what I'm describing possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way you can do this. You must first set NOCOUNT on so the rows affected does not show up. And then add the rows affected to print message using the system defined function @@rowcount:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--your code goes here
PRINT 'Got them! See (' + CONVERT(varchar,@@rowcount) +' rows affected)';
```

Comment: I tried exactly that. While I see the appearance I want, `@@rowcount` renders as 0 in all cases.  EDIT: i need to place the print statement _after_ my query...

Comment: Testing out my case, it looks like I don't need `SELECT * FROM sys.databases;` to correctly count records affected. I'd strike that out or replace with /* your t-sql code goes here .*/